# Angular - Multiple error interceptors

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I have an interceptor which handles errors and reacts to them. If there is an error, it will do `Observable.throw(err)`.

Now I need an interceptor which catches `401` statuses and then takes a stored refresh token and creates a new access token, sets the `authorization` header on `req` and tries the failed request again with the new header.

Here's the first error interceptor, notice the `Observable.throw(err)` part:

```
@Injectable()

export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private config: Config
  ) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
        catchError((err) => {

          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

            if (err.status === 401) {
              this.config.onUnauthorized(err);
            }
            else {
              this.config.onHttpError(err);
            }
          }

          return Observable.throw(err);
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the second interceptor:

```
@Injectable()

export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private api: Api, private cs: ClientStorage, private router: Router) { }

  private getNewAccessToken(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    console.log(0);
    return this.api.post<any>('token', null, {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: this.cs.getItem(AppConstants.appState).refreshToken,
      scope: 'user'
    });
  }

  private appendAccessToken(req, token) {
    console.log(1, token)
    return req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const appState = this.cs.getItem(AppConstants.appState);
    const accessToken = appState ? appState.accessToken : null;

    return next.handle(this.appendAccessToken(req, accessToken))
      .pipe(
        catchError((error: any) => {
          console.log(error);
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

            if (error.status === 401) {

              console.log('Unauthorized');

              return this.getNewAccessToken(req, next)
                .pipe(
                  mergeMap((res) => {

                  this.cs.setItem(AppConstants.appState, {...appState, accessToken: res.access_token});

                  return next.handle(this.appendAccessToken(req, res.access_token));
                })
              );
            }
            else if (error.status === 403) {
              this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
          }
          else {
            console.log(3)
            return Observable.throw(error);
          }
        })
      );
  }
};
```

The problem here is that the interceptor I've added doesn't seem to do anything, it initialises and it intercepts http requests which are **not** errors but the `catchError` bit doesn't run if there's an error. The `catchError` of the `ErrorInterceptor` however runs as expected, so I believe that they interfere with each other.

How can I make my token interceptor work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement similar scenario. It is working as expected. Here is the [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3qav7u?file=src%2Fapp%2Finterceptor2.ts).

As such I don't see any problem with your code, but I am wondering that why you have passed "req" and "next" to *getNewAccessToken()* method. They are not used in the method.

Comment: Turns out the problem was something far deeper, had a 3rd party module which erased my own interceptors which caused them only to be run once and then they were completely gone from the execution..

Comment: Hi @Chrillewoodz, could you name that 3rd party module? I'm having a similar problem and I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: @RTYX I think it was this one https://github.com/aitboudad/ngx-loading-bar